# how to submit html form from behind code in c sharp

Tags: c#, javascript, php, forms

so i have this code that works perfect on PHP

as u can see it creates a HTML form and submit it using javascript...

any ideas how to the the same with c sharp ?

```
    public function redirect_url(){
        //print_r($this->response);exit;
        $content = <<<EOT
     <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" >
      <!--
      function OnLoadEvent() { document.downloadForm.submit(); }
      //-->
      </SCRIPT>
     <body OnLoad="OnLoadEvent();">
      <form name="downloadForm" action="{$this->response['result']['A']}" method="POST" >
        <INPUT type="hidden" name="ONE"   value="{$this->response['result']['B']}"    >
        <input type="hidden" name="TWO" value="$this->return_url"  >
        <input type="hidden" name="THREE"      value="{$this->response['result']['D']}"       >
      </form>
         </body>
          EOT;
        echo $content;exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c# you just create the html file and do

```
Response.Redirect("pathtomyhtmlpage.html");
```